# Testcases out of order in junit test report when using testng

Tags: junit, testng

Part of my testcases

```
@Test(priority = 1)
public void testRoles001_Post() {

}


/**
 * Test Method: Post Scenario:Test new insert action with correct data,later
 * for batch delete.
 */
@Test(priority = 2)
public void testRoles002_Post() {

}
```

but the junitreports was showed not in order as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter -->
<testsuite name="com.test.rest.testcase.common.RolesRestTest" tests="14" failures="0" timestamp="3 Dec 2016 16:13:35 GMT" time="38.868" errors="0">
   <testcase name="testRoles004_Post" time="2.596" classname="com.oracle.civic.test.rest.testcase.common.RolesRestTest"/>
   <testcase name="testRoles002_Post" time="1.224" classname="com.oracle.civic.test.rest.testcase.common.RolesRestTest"/>
   <testcase name="testRoles003_Post" time="0.764" classname="com.oracle.civic.test.rest.testcase.common.RolesRestTest"/>
  <testcase name="testRoles001_Post" time="2.680" classname="com.oracle.civic.test.rest.testcase.common.RolesRestTest"/>
</testsuite>
```

did anyone know how to make them in order?

Comment: Could you try with the latest version (6.10) and open an issue if it is still in the wrong order? https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues

Comment: @JulienHerr I thought `6.9.13.6` is the latest released. If its to be tested on that. When did `6.10` got released?

Comment: 6.10 is only available on jcenter for the moment but 6.9.13 should be enough.

Comment: @Qiang - if you are judging by the order of tests in report, that should not matter as the `JUnitReportReporter` doesn't take care of `priority` while setting the report parameters. What can matter is, if the order of execution of the methods is changed to from what is expected here. To try test this, you can simply print two different statements from the above `@Test` method and execute the code.

Comment: @nullpointer yes, you are right, the JUnitReportReporter doesn't take care of priority. I tried, the order random each time. I want to use ant and XML files in junitreport folder to generate a html, the order will be confused when the report were saw by others

Comment: @JulienHerr, i try the 6.10, but issue was still there, i will open a bug, thx      `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  <repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>jcenter</id>
    <name>bintray</name>
    <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>`

Comment: @Qiang - I would be curious to learn as to why does execution order matter in a test report ? Just trying to understand the intent.

Comment: @JulienHerr [issue link on Github](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1262)

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan Thanks for your help, another question, how can i get the latest testng using maven, which version i needed? or need to wait for the new release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]The issue had been fix with bug [#1262](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1262) and please using the latest version 6.10.1-SNAPSHOT
[repositories url](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/testng/testng/6.10.1-SNAPSHOT/)

thanks testng team's support!